# How to display Group name also along with dropdown list items using jquery multiselect in mustache

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, mustache

I'm using mustache.js for rendering my page. Here is the snippet of what I'm trying to do:

```
{{#items}}

  <optgroup label ="Countries">   

<option >

{{name}} // json data
</option> 
 </optgroup> 


{{/items}}
```

The items contain the json data and I'm trying to render it in a form of a table using the jquery multiselect plugin.

[Here](http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/) is the jquery widget that I'm using, I'm trying to add a label on top of the options, i.e

```
Countries:
      Afghanistan
      Albania...and so on
```

Any ideas how can it be implemented?  I tried using the "optgroup", howevevr it doesn't work. Maybe I'm not using it the right way.
Any ideas appreciated!!!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optgroup should be out of the {{#items}}

```
<select>
  <optgroup label ="Countries">   
{{#items}}
     <option>{{name}}</option> 
{{/items}}
 </optgroup>
</select>
```

This will generate proper HTML.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didnt work..:( so just to make sure, i have a html template that has <select></select> and the #items are dynamically generated...do u have any other idea??? i tried on every single forum to ask for this issue...i havent found the ans yet..:(